# PayPal Sandbox: Your session has ended

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Even though I am using my buyer test account, when I run the paypal.billingAgreement.create, I am redirected to a page that states:

"This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."

My logs show no exceptions (partially shown below):

Billing Plan state changed to CREATED
For approving subscription via Paypal, first redirect user to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7TT13145TK360674X
Payment token is: EC-7TT13145TK360674X

Sequence of my code is:

1. paypal.billingPlan.create
2. paypal.billingPlan.update
3. paypal.billingAgreement.create

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using Cloud9 online IDE.

My best guess is that C9 is rotating IP addresses for each call, and PayPal is validating not only on the token but also the IP Address.

Comment: Thanks for the response.